# Download with <iframe> : works just one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a webservice sending me an excel file, call is made via Ajax with the following logic:

1. Send a "create file" request.
2. Ask for progress, server will return numbers between 0 and 100, client will update a progress bar with it.
3. Once received 100 update "src" element of iframe so to start download

Download with iframe is, till now, the only way to make download work with internet explorer so I'd like to keep it.

These are my iframe and progress bar:

```
<iframe width="1" height="1" style="display:none" src="{{downloadLink}}"></iframe>

<progressbar class="progress" value="reportProgress" type="success" >
                {{reportProgressL}}
    </progressbar>
```

And this is my angular js procedure:

```
$scope.startDownload = function() {
    $scope.reportProgress = 0;
    $scope.reportProgressL = "0%";

    var promise = $http.get('/myServiceCall/createFile');
    promise.then(
            function(payload){
                console.log('success ');
                console.log(payload);
            },
            function(error){
                $scope.showAlert('danger',error);
            });

    $scope.askProgress();
};


$scope.askProgress = function(){
    $http.get('/myServiceCall/progress').success(function(response, status, headers, config){

        $scope.reportProgress = response.data;
        if(response.data < 100){
            $scope.reportProgressL = response.data+"%";
            $timeout(function() {$scope.askProgress();}, 1000); 
        }else{
            console.log('Server elaboration completed, download should start shortly...');
            $scope.reportProgressL = "Done!";
            $scope.downloadLink = '/myServiceCall/getFile'; //setting the src iframe attribute: this will start download
        }
    }).error(function(err, status, headers, config){
        alert('Error: '+err+" "+status);
    });
};
```

Above code works fine...but just one time! Unless reloading page setting the "src" attribute again won't do anything. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you set the `src` attribute the new value is the same as the old. The browser doesn't detect that it has changed, and doesn't reload the `iframe`. You should try setting a `?random=###` parameter with a random value so that the attribute changes.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help.